# Capturing UDP multicast packets in python on a apecific network adapter

Tags: python, sockets, networking, multicast

I have a sensor that sends udp packets on mulitcast group 224.0.2.2 to port 42102. It is connected to one of several network adapters in a computer, that has the address 10.13.1.100 assigned to it.
The packets are visible as expected in Wireshark on the specified interface.
The code I'm currently using:

```
import socket
import struct

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('224.0.2.2', 42102)
sock.bind(server_address)

# Tell the kernel that we want to join a multicast group
# The address for the multicast group is the third parameter
group = socket.inet_aton('224.0.2.2')
mreq = struct.pack('4sL', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Set the interface to listen on
interface = socket.inet_aton('10.13.1.100')
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, interface)

# Receive messages
while True:
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print('Received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address))
    print(data)
```

This reaches the `recvfrom` command and hangs, suggesting the socket is not receiving anything.
I suspect there is some configuration error.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should not bind on a multicast address. Try ```server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 42102)```. Also setting the ```IP_MULTICAST_IF``` option on the receiver is meaningless.

Comment: @relent95 *"You should not bind on a multicast address"* that's acceptable if you only want to receive traffic from that single multicast address, not any others or any unicast traffic.

Comment: Yes, @dbush is right, my mistake. You can bind on a multicast address. Looking the code again, you did wrong on packing the struct. Try ```struct.pack('4sI', group, socket.INADDR_ANY)```. On a 64bit machine, the size of 'L' in native mode is 8 byte.

Comment: The `224.0.2.2` multicast group is registered for SUN RPC PMAPPROC_CALLIT, and I doubt the sensor is using it correctly.

Comment: The actual issue ended up being bad network interface configuration. The messages were on a specific VLAN i had to capture them there =\

Answer (score 2):

By joining the multicast group on interface `socket.INADDR_ANY`, you'll telling the OS to pick one interface to listen on, which may not be the one you want.  You should set this to the specific interface IP.

```
group = socket.inet_aton('224.0.2.2')
interface = socket.inet_aton('10.13.1.100')
mreq = struct.pack('4sI', group, interface)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
```

Setting `IP_MULTICAST_IF` does *not* specify which interface to listen on.  It specifies which interface to **send** multicast traffic from.